# How to replace "values with more than one decimal" with "nan" in a given column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a data frame in which one of the columns (dtype = float64) has a set of values such as:

```
129.0
nan
100.0
87.0
40.0
344.992
130.0
101.0
227.0
147.0
190.0
83.0
-144.63542183979368
```

I wish to replace all the values with more than one decimal places to nan. The values with more than one decimal places, both positive and negative are actually junk values. Only the positive values with single decimal place ending with .0 are genuine.

So, in above case, -144.63542183979368 and 344.992 should be replaced with nan. The modified data frame column should become like this:

```
129.0
nan
100.0
87.0
40.0
nan
130.0
101.0
227.0
147.0
190.0
83.0
nan
```

How do I go about doing this?

At the end, after removing junk float values, I would like to change the dtype to integer (which can be done once the improper float values are removed).

Comment: Are your values strings @GauravDVerma?

Comment: the dtype is float64 for this column

Comment: what do you expect from a number like 83.3? is it good or not? convert to NaN or keep?

Comment: Even if has a single decimal place apart from 0, it's a bad/incorrect value... it needs to be replaced with nan..
So, 83.3 should be replaced with nan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

arr = [129.0 ,np.nan ,100.0 ,87.0, 40.0, 344.992, 130.0, 101.0, 227.0, 147.0, 190.0, 83.0, -144.63542183979368]
df = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=['example'])
print(df)

def convert(row):
    if row:
        conv = row % 1
        if conv > 0:
            return np.nan
        else:
            return row
    else:
        return np.nan

df['example'] = df['example'].apply(convert)

print(df)
```

Comment: sure, please upvote if it helped

Comment: done... using % was perhaps the need here and I'd missed on thinking like this.. Thanks again for help.